# Взаимодействие с UI из Service

Tags: java, android

Имею сервис для аудиоплеера, а так же `ProgressBar`, который мне нужно делать `setVisibility(View.GONE)` в определенный момент. Доступа к UI из сервиса нет, тогда как мне сделать слушатель для того, чтобы выполнять это действие? И если не сложно, то хотелось бы увидеть пример.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20594936/communication-between-activity-and-service

Comment: С помощью широковещательно передатчика/приемника